# Create bubbles with gestures/Movements like Apple's Music App in Android

Tags: android, gestures, motion

I want to implement something like Apple's new Music app which is synced with iTunes. Bubbles on the move, according to mood we can select a music, genre etc.

I want this type of gesture with moving bubbles in Android. Can anyone help me out, how to figure out and play with **Gestures** or **Motion Controls** of that bubbles anywhere in screen. Also is there any support library if available would be very helpful to implement and move further. The bubbles are to be created randomly by a web service call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution?

Comment: No bro.. Not yet. I had been playing with my own custom animations and gesture controls to get that thing done.

Comment: Hi @RaviKabra, Is the work that you are doing with custom animations that you mention on github?

Comment: Hie.. @user3740387 , Yes I was trying to achieve this via custom animation. Or u can say a user gesture control but something like a screen saver shows a bubbles moving around smoothly and I wanna make that same feel with the animations support and that will be completely dynamic. I want to achieve the same feeling like Apple music gives, like when you are in a track or a genre and the things inside it moves in a bubble like bundle and when u click or move anywhere in the screen it senses your gesture and moves the bubble there.

Comment: https://github.com/mohitKejriwal/Bubble-UI-Android.  May it help someone in future  .